# How to get all publications of a user?

Tags: mendeley

Using the new api.mendeley.com api, how do you get all documents of a user, i.e., the ones that appear in his "My Publications" folder? When I use `GET /documents` I get all documents, not just the ones authored by the user. If I then filter down to only those results that have `authored: true`, then I do only get documents authored by the user, but I seem to be missing a lot.

I think the answer is related to the question: How do I retrieve documents beyond the 500 count limit. I don't see a `start` or `offset` parameter that is usually used for pagination. Clearly this would be the culprit for the question at hand if a user has more than 500 documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct to use the GET /documents call and look for documents where "authored=true"

If you perform a search like "GET /documents?limit=500&view=all" you then need to paginate through the responses.

It is documented here on our [developer portal](http://dev.mendeley.com/reference/topics/pagination.html) and there is a worked example on [our blog](http://mendeleyapi.wordpress.com/2014/08/13/paginated-collections-an-example/)

Making it easier to retrieve 'My Publications' is something that is on our technical roadmap.

Comment: I'd still like to know how to get all user documents without using pagination